# No palm rejection on Xubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, touchpad

I replaced my Windows 10 with Xubuntu 18.04 LTS (yay!), but as expected, I've been met with some problems. One big problem is that there isn't palm rejection. This makes for plenty of accidental taps here and there, and it is frustrating because I can't type a sentence without random selections and clicks. I know little about code, am even scared of it, but I'm good at following instructions. So any help is appreciated, thank you.